# How can I create a personal for each account in django ? Note: not in admin site

Tags: python, django, web

I am a beginner and still learning Django. I am wondering how can I build a personal site for each account like Facebook , Instagram, etc.Thank you very much. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty big subject, so I am just going to give some pointers.

So you will need to keep track of users. It makes sense to use Djangos auth functionality as it most likely covers what you need to do already. (Unless of course your user needs some specific functionality not overed by Django's oen Auth User objects.)

This guy has a decent blog post on how to do that. You will need to write your own templates, and configure the urls, but most other stuff is done for you.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Then you are going to have to associate models in your application with users. So say you have an facebook type clone. Each Post would have a foreign key to a user. You are also going to need to set permissions so that only appropriate people can view appropriate posts. To be fair there in't an easy answer to this question as it depends a lot on the specifics of what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! Can I just write my own authentication by making forms for login? My project just an website for student register for using room in unversity, the user page just contains the student profile, room register form ,etc.How can I make these pages?

Comment: You could do that, but as Django has it already, it makes sense to use that. 

Here is a blog post I wrote showing how to login with an email rather than a username - I would be surprised if writing your own would take less code. (I didn't post the template code, but its not complicated).

https://colinkingswood.github.io/Django-Email-Login/